# Why there are 2 keywords when we define enum in c/objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I define enum this way:

```
typedef enum sortByWhatUpperType{
    //sortByRating=0,
    sortbyDistance=1,
    sortbyBuildingorProminent=0
} sortbyWhatBottomType;
```

Then I created a property

```
@property enum sortByWhatUpperType sortByWhat;
```

This is what autocomplete suggest me to make

```
-(void) setSortByWhat:(enum sortByWhatUpperType)sortByWhat
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:sortByWhat forKey:SortByWhat];
}
-(sortbyWhatBottomType) sortByWhat
{
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SortByWhat] unsignedIntValue];
}
```

So that enum seems to have 2 types. sortByWhatUpperType and sortbyWhatBottomType.

Why do we have 2 keywords? Why not just one? What am I missing? Which one is the true type?

Is enum sortByWhatUpperType are synonym with sortbyWhatBottomType?

Is there any insight?

This is the standard way of doing enum in objective-c right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined TWO types. An enum called `sortByWhatUpperType`, and an alias to is called `sortbyWhatBottomType`. The `typedef enum` statement has two parts to is - the enum and the typedef. You could've omitted the typedef and typed

enum sortByWhatUpperType{ 
    //sortByRating=0, 
    sortbyDistance=1, 
    sortbyBuildingorProminent=0 
};

But then whenever you want to declare a variable of that type, you'd need ty type `enum`. Aliasing lets you omit that.

The same syntax is true for `struct`s. But only in C. In C++ you can omit enum/struct/class by default even without a typedef.

Comment: Awesome.... So in C++ we don't need to do so. Yea if I think about it, forcing user to keep typing enum seems like a good programming practice. That way we know that the type is an enum. Or is it?

Comment: There are many ways to remind yourself which one is an enum and which one is a struct. Like naming conventions. And yes, unless you rename your files to .mm, C++ syntax rules don't not apply.